# Cut string from last capital letter till the end

Tags: javascript

I have a string variable, something like "thisMagazineRoomcode". I need slice this from "R" - last capital letter till the end of the string. Slice method doesn't suit me because I have different variable like "thisMagazineName" or "thisMagazineSquare" with different letter quantity after captial letter.

Comment: what is the expected o/p ?

Comment: i expect from "thisMagazineRoomcode" - "thisMagazine" or "thisMagazineName" - "thisMagazine"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method.

```js
console.log(
  'thisMagazineRoomcode'.replace(/[A-Z][^A-Z]*$/, '')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegExp.exec() or String.match()

```
var stringValue = "thisMagaizineRoomcode";
re = /[A-Z][^A-Z]*$/;
re.exec(stringValue);
stringValue.match(re);
```

This outputs an array, but if you need it as a string, you can just doing something like:

```
var result = re.exec(stringValue);
return result[0];
```

inside a function.

Comment: Just saw the comments on the original post. If you're basically looking to delete the last word, then Pranav's answer does the trick. If you need to "pop" the last word, my method works. Or you could create a function that does both and basically splits the string into two strings from the last capitalized word.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
/** check whether the input is capital letter or not
*/
function isCapitalLetter(c) {
  return c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'
}

/** revert string */
function revertString(str) {
  return str.split('').reverse().join('')
}

/** cut last capital letter till the end */
function cutLastWord(str) {
  const revertStr = revertString(str)
  
  for (let i = 0; i < revertStr.length; i++) {
    if (isCapitalLetter(revertStr[i])) {
      const revertResult = revertStr.substr(0, i + 1)
      const result = revertString(revertResult)
      console.log(result)
      break
    }
  }
}

/** run sample data */
cutLastWord('HelloWorld') // World
cutLastWord('Hello') // Hello
cutLastWord('IAmHero') // Hero
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function that does this job

```
function cutStr(str) {
            var regex = /[A-Z][^A-Z]*$/;
            return str.split(regex).join('');
        }

console.log(cutStr('thisIsRedmond')); // output 'thisIs'
```